# define table row space

Tags: html, css

**how to define table space?**

[image]

I want to make the space smaller and my icons do not disappear, also have a problem, having a small screen my icons are hidden

[image]

[image]

I need to keep the size of my icons when having the small screen, help pls

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="main-content-label mg-b-5">
    Simple Table
  </div>
  <p class="mg-b-20">Example of redash Simple Table.</p>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table mg-b-0 text-md-nowrap">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          @foreach($tipos as $tipo)
          <th><img style="height: 32px; width: 32px;" src="{{url($tipo->icono)}}" alt=""></th>
          @endforeach
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include the actual code for the snippet?

Comment: yes, it is included at the end of the post, https://pastebin.com/48mfSpSL

Comment: So what are the images for?

Comment: are the icons are in .png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS media queries to determine your icon's size when you the screen size decreases, and also remember to add this meta tag at the top of your Html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

also the to decrease the space between your table data use `margin` property or the table attribute `cellspacing`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this as it will help to create all the images in 1 row and help you to scroll if you will add more images:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="main-content-label mg-b-5">
            Simple Table
    </div>
    <p class="mg-b-20">Example of redash Simple Table.</p>
  <div class="scrollmenu">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RquOiuK.png" style="width:20%;height:30%;">

    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RquOiuK.png" style="width:20%;height:30%;">

    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RquOiuK.png" style="width:20%;height:30%;">

    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RquOiuK.png" style="width:20%;height:30%;">

    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RquOiuK.png" style="width:20%;height:30%;">

    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RquOiuK.png" style="width:20%;height:30%;">



  </div>
</div>
```

```
img{
height: 0.25rem;
font-size: 3.75em;
}
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

here is the link of my sample: [you can check here](https://jsfiddle.net/divya661/mz7xLncd/23/)

Comment: Now you can see them all, but is there any way to keep the horizontal scroll?https://i.imgur.com/Ui3fzWJ.png

Comment: can you please my query that "do you want to appear all the images in the vertical row instead of horizontal is this what you mean by horizontal scroll?"

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nPAa8te.png                                                                                          I need to keep the horizontal scroll bar and show the icons.
I need it in case there are many icons

Comment: @user13523236 I have made changes in my code, you can check them now. If I have got you correctly. Since I got only one icon link of repeated it multiple times as the other link contains only images of all the icons you have used and not separately.

Comment: Now, the horizontal scroll will appear only when you have multiple icons. You can adjust the no of icons you want to have by default without scroll accordingly. by making changes to the CSS